# Providing the size (const) of the member array as the constructor argument RELOADED

Tags: c++

I have gone through some of the threads on the same topic but they are really advanced like set and all. For someone just finding his footsteps in C++, what would be the best way to deal with this?

The following code gives me error:

```
class AStack {
    public:
        AStack(int size) : max_Size(size) {
        }
        void push(int);
        int pop();
        int top();
        bool isEmpty();
        void Flush();

    private:
        const int max_Size;
        int a[max_Size];
        int index = -1; // Index of the top most element
};
```

Comment: Fix the basic typos (like `AStack` vs. `Astack`), and don't make us guess what errors you get.

Comment: Oh dear...really messed that up, didn't I? Also, if max_Size is a static data member, then it makes no sense to initialize it using a constructor. So, made it non-static now.

Comment: It will have to be static, and initialised in the class, to be usable as a constant expression for the array size. If you want to specify the size at run-time, then you can't use a simple array; use a dynamic array like `std::vector`.

Comment: I see. I'm close to getting it now. Why can't it be static? All I know is that static is class property

Comment: I said it *must* be static (not that it can't), if you want to use it as a constant expression for the array size. It can't be static (and you can't use a simple array) if you want it to vary for different objects.

Comment: Wow, I've got a long way to go before understanding stuff. :(

Comment: In Java, I can initialize static variables friom outside the class without creating instances. How can I do that in C++?

Comment: In this case, to be usable as a constant expression within the class, you'll have to initialise it in the class. `static const int max_Size = whatever;`

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 options here.

1. Turn the class into a template and the depth parameter becomes a template argument. Then it is constant and you can create the array with respective size.
2. Use a std::vector for your internal array and use the `resize()` method.
3. Make max_depth a `static const uint32_t max_depth = 42;` (Initialize in-class) and then you can use that max_depth, too as size for array `a`.

Solution 1 looks then like this:

```
template <size_t max_depth>
class AStack
{
     // ...
     int a[max_depth];
};
```

Solution 2 then looks like this:

```
#include <vector>
class AStack
{
public:
    AStack( size_t max_depth )
    {
          a.resize(max_depth);
          // ...
    }
    // ...
    std::vector<int> a;
    // ...
};
```

Solution 3 would look like that:

```
class AStack
{
     static const int max_depth = 42;
     int a[max_depth];
     // ...
};
```

Fixed size c-arrays can only be declared with a constant array size expression.
The constructor affects the non static members of a class. The static const  members of a class are "hard-coded" initialized.

So if you want to allow users of that class to use it with varying stack sizes, you need option 1 or option 2. If you want to hard-code the stack size within the class, use option 3. Option 2 can also be done "manually" using operator new() or new() instead of a std::vector. But then you have much more to type, to check, and you will most likely have bugs which will not impress your instructor ;)

Comment: Hmmm...thank you. I understand the reason behind using vectors but we haven't been taught that and I wanted to impress my instructor by doing that using arrays. I guess it's impossible to initialize array that way?

Comment: No, only more dangerous as you will have to use dynamic memory operations to achieve the same effect std::vector does.

Comment: Simply put, you cannot define the size of a regular c-array in any "runtime determined" way. The size has to be constant as it is a part of determining sizeof(AStack) class and that size cannot change at runtime.

Comment: I understand that. I want to define it at compile time itself but through the constructor instead of hard coding.

Comment: You cannot use constructor to initialize static members. Constructors initialize instances, not the static part of a class. So you would use option 3 listed above and write the constant right in the declaration of max_depth as an assignment.

Comment: I see your point. Can you kindly elaborate the third solution as you have done for the first two please?

Comment: In Java, I can initialize static variables from outside the class without creating instances. How can I do that in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently this is a learning exercise, so the straight-forward solution with `std::vector` doesn't work for you. That means you need to use pointers and dynamic allocation.

Declare the array as a pointer instead:

```
int * a;
```

In the constructor, allocate the appropriate size array:

```
AStack(int size) : max_Size(size), a(new int[size])
```

And whenever you allocate memory, you need to free it when you're done with it. In this case, in the destructor.

```
~AStack() {
    delete [] a;
}
```

Because the destructor is no longer trivial, the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) suggests that you need a copy constructor and assignment operator too. I'll leave that part to you.

Comment: I want to become a genius like you one day. Thank you so much, Sir. Respect.

Comment: Hmmm...by assignment operator, do you mean overloading the  '=' operator?

Comment: @TrentBoult yes that's exactly what I mean. And thanks!